# Issues importing pytorch with conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, anaconda, pytorch

My system is:

```
 x86_64
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.1
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rebecca
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
```

I have recently installed pytorch since it is required for the use of the Python causal discovery toolbox, and I have installed it using Anaconda without the use of CUDA, like so:

conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch

This installation was successful, but when I try to run

```
import torch
```

in IDLE, it is not able to find the module. I realize that this question may be a redundancy, but I have searched through similar issues without finding anything that worked, and I am sort on time. Also, I am unfamiliar with Anaconda, so I am not sure how to get packages installed through it to work with the rest of Python. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use PyTorch, install it in your local environment using

```
conda create -n pytorch_env  python=3  
source activate pytorch_env   
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision -c pytorch
```

Go to python shell and import using the command

```
import torch
```